# Stealing bits from a std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, bit-manipulation, shared-ptr

I am currently working on a class assignment where I need to implement a lock-free linked list.  The structure of each of my nodes is essentially:

```
class Node {
    std::shared_ptr<Node> next;
    long long             key;
}
```

I need to somehow embed an extra bit of data into the "next" pointer.  I cannot use an extra boolean field, because the "next" pointer needs to be updated atomically using compare_exchange_strong().  I also have to use a std::shared_ptr for its garbage collection abilities; performing memory reclamation on a lock-free data structure is beyond the scope of what we have studied in the course so far.

If I were using a plain old pointer, I could use bit manipulation operators to "twiddle" the high bit of the pointer, but clearly this won't work, because once I twiddle the bit, the pointer points to an invalid memory location, and when the assignment operator attempts to access the control block, it will cause a segmentation violation.

Can anyone offer any insights on how I can accomplish this?

Oh, and for those who are curious, I am using g++-4.8.2 on a Linux system.

Comment: You could embed information in a custom deleter.

Comment: Do you know where I could find an example of something like this?

Comment: @DyP The deleter is per pointed-to-object, not per-shared-pointer, so I guess this is quite different.

Comment: @DanielFrey: But that custom deleter could certainly strip off that extra bit which is causing problems. The main problem I see is that the "twiddled" pointer is likely to get its own independent reference count.

Comment: @MSalters You can share ownership of two unrelated pointers.

Comment: it's not clear to me how you're using `compare_exchange_strong` with `shared_ptr`

Comment: @SamMiller There's a special overload for [`compare_exchange_strong`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) that takes two raw pointers to `shared_ptr` and a `shared_ptr` by value.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to mix two different things here.

Meddling with the pointer in a shared_ptr does not strike me as a good idea. The shared pointer is thread safe, but you can accomplish that yourself if you are using atomic operations.

Anyway, a custom deleter as suggested before is done like this;

```
struct d { void operator()(foo* f){ delete f; } };
```

...and you create a shared_ptr w/this using;

```
shared_ptr<bar> b(new bar, d());
```

...but why not use atomic operations to start with?

Cheers!

Comment: I wanted to use shared_pointers for their memory management benefits; you don't have to worry about when to delete them.  However, apparently in gcc-4.8.2 they aren't 100% thread-safe; in one of my implementations, I was getting really weird "calling a pure virtual function" errors.  I ended up writing my own memory manager that used hazard pointers to determine when it was safe to reuse a data element.  I also had to write a lock-based approach as well, and the custom memory manager was about 300-400% faster than using the shared pointers...

Comment: Regarding the "pure virtual function" errors; I get that sometimes when I call a virtual function from a base class destructor. Sometimes I put a `cout << "Destroying: " << *this` in the destructor for logging reasons and if the `operator<<` contains virtual function calls... :/